# How to set maximum length of a NSTextField without overwriting the last character?

Tags: swift, string, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I'm not able to find any inbuilt property for this. Is there a way by which I can manually achieve this? How to set maximum length of a NSTextField without overwriting the last character ? They shouldn't be able to enter the next character after maximum limit is reached.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set maximum characters (to one) in a NSTextfield in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589503/set-maximum-characters-to-one-in-a-nstextfield-in-swift)

Comment: The answers for the one you mentioned are not convincing.I'm not considering this as a duplicate since no convincing answers are found

Comment: exactly, those solutions aren't properly written

Answer (score 0):

*Hope this will help you,*

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj{
  if([Textfield .stringValue length]>8)//you can set the maximum 
  {
      [[Textfield currentEditor]deleteBackward:nil];
  }
}
```

**Note:Set your textfiled's delegate to self.
Eg:textfiled.delegate = self;*

Answer (score -1):

NSTextField delegate have a function that you can use to check length of text

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)affectedCharRange replacementString:(NSString *)replacementString
{
}
```

If you don't want to apply this delegate function every where you use `NSTextField`. You can subclass a CustomTextField.

Hope this help.